# check if exact string is prsent in pandas dataframe or not

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe in pandas

```
 code        skills  
 12          sql, r, hadoop
 13          python
 14          r, matlab
 15          ruby, python
```

I want to flag 1 and 0 where I found exact occurance of `r` following is my desired dataframe.

```
 code        skills             r  
 12          sql, r, hadoop     1   
 13          python             0
 14          r, matlab          1
 15          ruby, python       0
```

I am doing following in pandas

```
 df['r'] = df['skills'].eq(' r,').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `apply` (*just another alternative*):

```
df['r']=df.skills.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: 'r' in map(str.strip, x)).astype(int)
print(df)
```

---

```
   code          skills  r
0    12  sql, r, hadoop  1
1    13          python  0
2    14       r, matlab  1
3    15    ruby, python  0
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use some `regex` to achieve this task.

```
pattern = '(?:, r)|(?:r,)'

df['r'] = df.skills.str.contains(pattern).astype(int)

   code          skills  r
0    12  sql, r, hadoop  1
1    13          python  0
2    14       r, matlab  1
3    15    ruby, python  0
```